# C# override base class collection type

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have a base class with

```
     public abstract class BaseClass
    {
     ICollection<int> Numbers {get;set;}
    }
```

IS there a way of getting the below result?

```
    public abstract class SubClass : BaseClass
    {
     override ObservableCollection<int> Numbers {get;set;}
    }
```

So the subclass has an observablecollection or is there a design pattern I could implement?

Comment: You can't change types when overriding. Consider implementing two interfaces, one with `ICollection` and one that is more specific. Code that uses these would have to go look for the specific interface they want to interact with. However, do you need to? Any code that has to support `BaseClass` would have to support `ICollection<int>`.

Comment: Exposing a *settable* collection property tends to be problematic. What happens when someone does `((BaseClass)new SubClass()).Numbers = new SomeOtherCollectionType();`? (Even in the general case, you usually wish to retain ownership on the collection and not let others change it out on you but here it's especially bad)

Comment: True I never considered that, I'm only looking at changing the collection type because I'm using a ViewModel that needs an observable collection but of the same type as the data model.

Comment: You can, but think obout other options. `new ObservableCollection<int> Numbers {get;set;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics can help you achieve similar behavior:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : ICollection<int>
{
    public T Numbers { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SubClass : BaseClass<ObservableCollection<int>>
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override it like that.

One solution might be creating a new property with a different name as followed:

```
public abstract class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> ObservableNumbers => (ObservableCollection<int>)Numbers;
}
```

Or as followed: (if you really need to be able to set it)

```
public abstract class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> ObservableNumbers
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<int>)Numbers; }
        set { Numbers = value; }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to make the `Numbers` property public or internal!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below adding "new" keyword

```
public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual ICollection<int> Numbers { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class SubClass : BaseClass
    {
        public new ObservableCollection<int> Numbers { get; set; }
    }
```